# Using react-native-tab-view in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-tab-view

```
react: "16.11.0",
react-native: "0.62.2",
react-native-navigation: "^6.4.0",
react-native-tab-view: "^2.14.0",
```

I'm trying to use [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) with [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) V3.

So far I able to use a registered-component in this way:

```
import EventsScreen from './EventsScreen';
function registerScreens() 
{
    ...
    Navigation.registerComponent('com.events.EventsScreen', () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(EventsScreen));
    ...
}
```

In the `React.Component` page where I wants the tab-view:

```
import EventsScreen from './EventsScreen';

let renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: EventsScreen,
    second: AddEventScreen   });
```

The above way works, but I can not pass any props to the EventsScreen. I was more likely to expect a design something like,

```
{
   component: 'com.events.EventsScreen',
   passProps: { .. }
}
```

Following does not work if I tried in this way:

```
let renderScene = SceneMap({
        first: 'com.events.EventsScreen',
        second: 'com.events.AddEventScreen'   });
```

What is the correct way to provide a `React.Component` view to `SceneMap` with props?

Answer (score 0):

I able to pass *props* to `renderScene` property in this way:

```
renderScene = ({ route }) => {
      switch (route.key) {
        case 'first':
          return <EventsScreen {...this.props}/>;
        case 'second':
          return <SecondRoute />;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    };

    render()
    {
        return (
                <TabView
                    onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
                    navigationState={this.state}
                    renderScene={this.renderScene}
                    initialLayout={initialLayout}
                    style={styles.container}
                />

        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are trying to use the screens registered with RNN to be used as one of `tabs` in `react-native-tab-view`.

What you want to do instead is to register a component/screen which contains `react-native-tab-view` and have components/screens you wish to use as `tabs` as normal react component (do not register these with RNN).

You will end up something like this:

```
// index.js
import Home from './route/Home

Navigation.registerComponent('Home', () => Home)

// Home.js
import { TabView, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view'
import EventScreen from './route/Home/tabs/EventScreen'

const renderScene = () => {
  return SceneMap({
    eventScreen: () => <EventScreen {...eventScreenProps} />
  })
}

return (
  <TabView
    renderScene={renderScene}
    {...others}
  />
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I see it's another way to implementation. I'd glad to hear what you think this advantages over the other.

Comment: Hmm, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to use RNN registered component as one of tabs in `react-native-tab-view`. You should not register the screens that you are going to be using as one of the tabs (eg EventsScreen) as react-native-tab-view is expecting a normal React component.

Comment: Since you mentioned I noticed that in my original solution, I am actually using the EventsScreen directly and nor in a RNN way! So now if I removed the RNN registration for the EventsScreen my application still running well! Having the change our codes are more or less same I guess ) Thanks!